# Using custom JS plugins with WordPress?

Tags: plugins, themes, javascript

How can I use something like particles.js with Divi?

I've tried putting the following code into the Divi Intergration page in the body (this is where it works on non-wordpress site)

```
    <div id="particles-js"></div> 
     <!-- PARTICLES.JS LIBRARY -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <!-- PARTICLES.JS SCRIPT -->
<script>
    particlesJS("particles-js", {
        "particles": {
            "number": {
                "value": 160,
                "density": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "value_area": 800
                }
            },
            "color": {
                "value": "#ffffff"
            },
            "shape": {
                "type": "circle",
                "stroke": {
                    "width": 0,
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                "polygon": {
                    "nb_sides": 5
                },
                "image": {
                    "src": "img/github.svg",
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100
                }
            },
            "opacity": {
                "value": 1,
                "random": true,
                "anim": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "speed": 1,
                    "opacity_min": 0,
                    "sync": false
                }
            },
            "size": {
                "value": 3,
                "random": true,
                "anim": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "speed": 4,
                    "size_min": 0.3,
                    "sync": false
                }
            },
            "line_linked": {
                "enable": false,
                "distance": 150,
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "opacity": 0.4,
                "width": 1
            },
            "move": {
                "enable": true,
                "speed": 1,
                "direction": "none",
                "random": true,
                "straight": false,
                "out_mode": "out",
                "bounce": false,
                "attract": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "rotateX": 600,
                    "rotateY": 600
                }
            }
        },
        "interactivity": {
            "detect_on": "window",
            "events": {
                "onhover": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "mode": "grab"
                },
                "onclick": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "mode": "push"
                },
                "resize": true
            },
            "modes": {
                "grab": {
                    "distance": 400,
                    "line_linked": {
                        "opacity": 1
                    }
                },
                "bubble": {
                    "distance": 250,
                    "size": 0,
                    "duration": 2,
                    "opacity": 0,
                    "speed": 3
                },
                "repulse": {
                    "distance": 400,
                    "duration": 0.4
                },
                "push": {
                    "particles_nb": 4
                },
                "remove": {
                    "particles_nb": 2
                }
            }
        },
        "retina_detect": true
    });
</script>
```

and I've also put the following in the custom CSS for the page in the visual builder:

```
    canvas {
    display: block; 
    }

    #particles-js { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 1%, #0c0c24 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -50; 
    }
```

It just doesn't work, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome (I'm new myself, too).

First and foremost, I **highly** recommend setting up a *Child Theme* for your *Divi* installation; that way any modifications you make won't be overwritten when *Elegant Themes* do an update.

That said, the best way at this is to use WordPress' native en queuing system. In your `functions.php` file, add the following:

```
function enqueue_particles() {
    wp_register_style('particles-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/particle.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_style('particles-styles');    
    wp_enqueue_script('particles-cdn', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('particles-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/particle.js', array('particles-cdn'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_particles');
```

...then create 2 new files in your theme directory:

**particle.css**

```
canvas {
    display: block; 
}

#particles-js { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 1%, #0c0c24 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -50; 
}
```

...and **particle.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        particlesJS("particles-js", {
            "particles": {
                "number": {
                    "value": 160,
                    "density": {
                        "enable": true,
                        "value_area": 800
                    }
                },
                "color": {
                    "value": "#ffffff"
                },
                "shape": {
                    "type": "circle",
                    "stroke": {
                        "width": 0,
                        "color": "#000000"
                    },
                    "polygon": {
                        "nb_sides": 5
                    },
                    "image": {
                        "src": "img/github.svg",
                        "width": 100,
                        "height": 100
                    }
                },
                "opacity": {
                    "value": 1,
                    "random": true,
                    "anim": {
                        "enable": true,
                        "speed": 1,
                        "opacity_min": 0,
                        "sync": false
                    }
                },
                "size": {
                    "value": 3,
                    "random": true,
                    "anim": {
                        "enable": false,
                        "speed": 4,
                        "size_min": 0.3,
                        "sync": false
                    }
                },
                "line_linked": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "distance": 150,
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "opacity": 0.4,
                    "width": 1
                },
                "move": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "speed": 1,
                    "direction": "none",
                    "random": true,
                    "straight": false,
                    "out_mode": "out",
                    "bounce": false,
                    "attract": {
                        "enable": false,
                        "rotateX": 600,
                        "rotateY": 600
                    }
                }
            },
            "interactivity": {
                "detect_on": "window",
                "events": {
                    "onhover": {
                        "enable": false,
                        "mode": "grab"
                    },
                    "onclick": {
                        "enable": true,
                        "mode": "push"
                    },
                    "resize": true
                },
                "modes": {
                    "grab": {
                        "distance": 400,
                        "line_linked": {
                            "opacity": 1
                        }
                    },
                    "bubble": {
                        "distance": 250,
                        "size": 0,
                        "duration": 2,
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "speed": 3
                    },
                    "repulse": {
                        "distance": 400,
                        "duration": 0.4
                    },
                    "push": {
                        "particles_nb": 4
                    },
                    "remove": {
                        "particles_nb": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            "retina_detect": true
        });
    }
);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfect! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Can I inbox you for a small question about divi?

Comment: You can, but it's been a while. I'm not sure how helpful I'll be :-/

Comment: I don't think there's a way on inboxing on here. Anyway I'm trying to use Bootstrap Modals and I'm not sure how to apply them to the Filterable Portfolio in Divi. Do you have any experience with using Bootstrap Modals in WordPress?